# Global Sections over Proper Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $C$ be a proper curve (so separated, of finite type, and universally closed) over a field $k$.

Why is $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C) = (\mathcal{O}_C(C))$ not zero?

My ideas: Because $X$ proper over $k$ (field, so Noetherian) and $\mathcal{O}_C \in Coh(C)$ , we get that $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, but why it can't be zero space?

Comment: won't it contain the constant functions?

Comment: Should the constant functions be contained there? If yes, why? Another idea would be to use the fact that $C$
has a closed point $c$, such that $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ is a local ring of Krull dimension one, so not zero. But I don't khow if I can lift a nonzero element of $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ to a global section...

Comment: $C$ is a scheme over $k$, so you get a ring morphism $k\to H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$.

Comment: @user363120: Yes, but why it can't be a zero morphism onto zero ring $H^0(\mathcal{O}_C,C)$? $0$ is in a trivial way a k-algebra too, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but if this is morphism is trivial, then the structure morphism $C\to Spec(k)$ is trivial. Since for each open affine $Spec(A)$ of $C$, $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra (via this structure morphism), this implies that $A=0$ and thus $C=\varnothing$.

Comment: @user363120: ...and this argument would imply that every $R$-scheme $X$ has non trivial $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, right?

Comment: Good point. In fact, if $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$, then the existence of the restriction ring morphism $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$, for $U\subset X$ open, forces $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$. Hence $X=\varnothing$ as above.